# how to make mod_topbanner show 2 images to 2 different links

Tags: php, joomla

I'm, trying to get the Joomla topbanner to show 2 different images leading to 2 different links, so I changed the following code,

from this:

```
// get a parameter from the module's configuration
$imgname = $params->get('imgname');
$imgwidth = $params->get('imgwidth', '');
$imgheight = $params->get('imgheight', '90');
$imgtarget = $params->get('imgtarget', '');
$imgpath = JURI::base().'images/stories/';

$html   = "<a href='".$imgtarget."' target='_blank'>";
$html   .= "<img src='".$imgpath.$imgname."' border='0' alt=''       width='".$imgwidth."' height='".$imgheight."'>";
$html   .= "</a>"; 
echo $html;
```

to this:

```
// get a parameter from the module's configuration
$imgname = $params->get('imgname');
$imgwidth = $params->get('imgwidth', '');
$imgheight = $params->get('imgheight', '90');
$imgtarget = $params->get('imgtarget', '');
$imgpath = JURI::base().'images/stories/';

//split up image and targets
list($image1,$image2) = explode(',',$imgname);
list($target1,$target2) = explode(',',$imgtarget);

//steps
//divide image into 2 using any image editing tool
//upload to server
//set up images separated by comma in admin
//add second target to admin separated by comma


$html   = "<a href='".$target1."' target='_blank'>";
$html   .= "<img src='".$imgpath.$image1."' border='0' alt='' width='".$imgwidth."'     height='".$imgheight."'>";
$html   .= "</a>"; 
$html   = "<a href='".$target2."' target='_blank'>";
$html   .= "<img src='".$imgpath.$image2."' border='0' alt='' width='".$imgwidth."'    height='".$imgheight."'>";
$html   .= "</a>"; 
echo $html;
```

I edited it in the back end with a delimiter but it is only reading the second image and link.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
$html   = "<a href='".$target2."' target='_blank'>";
```

You're not cocatenating `$html`, you're reassigning it.  All the old information is lost.  Simply do this:

```
$html   .= "<a href='".$target2."' target='_blank'>";
```